# I have a problem with using pytesseract it shows "Could not open file"

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

> I'm using pytesseract and it says 'could not open file' and the file is in >the same directory, How to solve this?"
>
> I watched a video and do the same as in the video but it still gives error.
>
> PS C:\Users\hp-p\Desktop\test> pytesseract.exe -l eng pop.png
>      ERROR: Could not open file "pop.png"
>      PS C:\Users\hp-p\Desktop\test>